# Semidirect product of two linear groups

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ two connected linear Lie groups. Is $G\ltimes H$ also linear?

Comment: If $G$ and $H$ are complex  linear *algebraic* groups, that is, affine algebraic groups, and $G$ acts on $H$, then $H\rtimes G$ is an affine algebraic group, hence linear. It seems that the same holds over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Thank you! Is there a particular reference you could suggest for the above fact?

Comment: If $G$ and $H$ are  linear algebraic groups over $\Bbb C$, then they are  affine algebraic groups over $\Bbb C$, and therefore  they are affine varities. Since $H\rtimes G$ is, as a variety, isomorphic to $H \times G$, it is an affine variety. Thus $H\rtimes G$ is an affine algebraic group.

Comment: An affine algebraic group admits a faithful linear representation $\rho$; see, for example, Theorem 8 in Section 3.1.6 of Arkady L. Onishchik and Ernest B. Vinberg, Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990. Thus $H\rtimes G$ is isomorphic to a linear algebraic group.

Comment: If the complex algebraic groups  $G$, $H$, and the action of $G$ on $H$ are actually defined over $\Bbb R$, then $H\rtimes G$ is an affine algebraic group over $\Bbb R$. Let $\rho$ be as above (defined over $\Bbb C$); then $\rho\oplus\bar\rho$ is a faithful linear representation over $\Bbb R$. We conclude that $H\rtimes G$ is isomorphic to a linear algebraic group defined over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453236/semidirect-product-of-two-linear-groups#comment1172478_453236), of course there is also the matter, easily verified, of checking that the group morphisms are variety morphisms.  (Second part of comment deleted; I misread what you wrote.)

Comment: Discrete groups are particular cases of Lie groups. The answer is no because there are iterated extensions of torsion-free abelian groups that are not linear (e.g., the free 3-step solvable group on 3 generators). [If one assumes the Lie groups are connected, this should be specified]

Comment: The group Heisenberg modulo discrete subgroup of the center is a semidirect product $(\mathbf{R}^2/\mathbf{Z})\rtimes\mathbf{R}$ and is not linear, while both summands are linear. Over $\mathbf{C}$ it works as well with complex Lie groups.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi you seem to assume that the action is algebraic as well.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the example! How one could see that this quotient is not indeed linear? Because, I would say it is the usual Heisenberg matrix representation with only the center is now modulo 1, isn't it?

Comment: @YCor: Indeed, I do assume that  the action is algebraic as well.

Comment: @M.Han for a continuous complex representation, after conjugation, the group has to map into upper triangular matrices, hence its derived subgroup maps into upper unipotent matrices. But this derived subgroup is compact and this can only map trivially.

Comment: @YCor I got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is a semidirect product $\mathbf{R}\ltimes (\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})$ that is not linear. Namely, the quotient of the Heisenberg group by a lattice of its center has this form.

Replacing $\mathbf{R}$ with $\mathbf{C}$ also yields an example in the realm of complex Lie groups.

These are classical examples of non-linear Lie groups. Indeed, if $G$ is a solvable connected Lie group then (the closure of) its derived subgroup is simply connected (indeed, taking a complex representation, one can triangulate it, and this directly follows since every closed connected subgroup of the upper unipotent group is simply connected).